# Add custom parameters to Spring Security oAuth2 login

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a web-app written in Java using Spring as a back-end framework. I implemented the login through Facebook and Google using Spring Social OAuth2. I was wondering if there was a way to pass extra parameters to the login request.

```java
@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public class CustomOAuth2UserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private AccountHolderService accountHolderService;

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2User oAuth2User = super.loadUser(oAuth2UserRequest);

        try {
            return processOAuth2User(oAuth2UserRequest, oAuth2User);
        }catch (Exception | EmailAlreadyTakenException | UsernameNotAvailableException | PostTypeNotFoundException ex) {
            // Throwing an instance of AuthenticationException will trigger the OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause());
        }
    }

    private OAuth2User processOAuth2User(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User oAuth2User) throws EmailAlreadyTakenException, UsernameNotAvailableException, PostTypeNotFoundException {
        OAuth2UserInfo oAuth2UserInfo = OAuth2UserInfoFactory.getOAuth2UserInfo(oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId(), oAuth2User.getAttributes());
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(oAuth2UserInfo.getEmail())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Id not found from OAuth2 provider");
        }
        User user;
        try {
            user = userService.getBySocialId(oAuth2UserInfo.getId());
            return new CustomUserDetails(user);
        } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
            try {
                User u = userService.getByEmail(oAuth2UserInfo.getEmail());
                throw new EmailAlreadyTakenException("email-already-taken");
            }catch (UserNotFoundException ex){
                // create user
                User u = userService.addUser(user);
                return new CustomUserDetails(u);
            }
        }
    }

    private User buildSocialProvidedUser(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2UserInfo oAuth2UserInfo) {
        ...
        return user;
    }

    private String generateUsername(String username){
        ...
    }

}
```

I would like to have in this class an extra parameter passed when the user pressed the login/signup button. This parameter is needed to show custom information to the user after the login/signup phase.
Even more, right now, even if the user does not already have an account (and so he just signed up) or he already has one (and he just logged in) I cannot differentiate these two different process. Is there a way to have different results?

Comment: It's not really an issue for OAuth.  Whether a user has logged in to a given application or not should be tracked by that application.  Consider persisting logins or even just a flag in your app.

Comment: Ok so you mean like, using JavaScript send a request to the backend and store the user choice during the signup phase and persist it somewhere? For instance, if he presses on Login with facebook I'm going to send a request to my backend before storing that he chose Login with facebook and then send the request to Facebook?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to trigger some behaviour only after signup?
If so, you wouldn't pass this information from the front end. I.e. "Hello, it's my first time here".
You'd track it from the back-end. I.e. This app has no record of this user logging in before.
That way your UI should be able to ask the server if it's a new user or not (via API call) and decide if they need to see your signup information.

Comment: Yes exactly. Mmmh ok I see. So every time a page is loaded I have to ask myself if this is a new user or not.... is it not bad in a performance way?

Comment: Not really.  Though it depends on the nature of your app.  If you're using a static-UI driven by API calls, then 1 call per session would do the job.  On the other hand if you're using server pages you could have logic in there to say it they're a new user, redirect them to page X

Comment: It's a single page web app. But the point is that after the Social login/signup it gets redirect to the same page regardless from what just happend. So every time I load that page I have to ask myself if that's a new user and then redirect the request to the appropriate page. I would have liked to redirect the user automatically after the login/signup based on what just happend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203664/discussion-between-andy-n-and-stefano-sambruna).